# Why will Heroku git push to my staging app but no longer to my production app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

Until recently I've had no problems with git pushes to my staging app and to my production app on Heroku.

Recently I let my staging app get a few commits ahead of my production app while I fiddled with a problem.

Now I can still successfully git push to my staging app, but whenever I try to git push to my production app I get:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 227, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (176/176), done.
Received disconnect from 50.19.85.156: 10: user closed connection
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:testivate.git'
```

I estimate that my total app is less than 10MB, as the app's folder on my local system is 84.4MB, but it contains a 75.7MB /tmp/ folder that I've excluded from my commits via the `.gitignore` file.

How can I diagnose and fix this problem?

Comment: this can help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546054/error-deploying-to-heroku

Comment: Thanks. Saw that. None of the technical solutions posted there were relevant to me. (E.g. I didn't have any large files.) But contacted Heroku support directly (as one of the commenters did) seems to have resolved the problem.